How can I make buttons correspond to a field in a database table?
I am using Python with guizero to build a grid of buttons:
from guizero import App, PushButton, Waffle, Text

def button_click(x, y):
    print(f"Button {x+1}-{y+1} was clicked!")

app = App("Button-Grid", width=600, height=800)

button_grid = Waffle(app, width=8, height=8, dim=50, pad=5, dotty=True, command=button_click)
name = Text(app, text="")

app.display()

I have an SQLite database with one table. I connect to the database like:
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("my_database.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

I want a function that when a button is pushed a corresponding value in the table of my database is updated: push a button -> update my_table set a_column = some_value;. How can I make every button in the grid correspond to a single field in the database table? Maybe like:
def update_db(x, y):
  cursor.execute("update <my_table> set {x+1}-{y+1} = <some_value>;")

This function will be executed whenever a button is pushed. But how do I single out a button and make it correspond to a column/field in a database?
